# Prove that $X$ is uniformly distributed

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a independent sequence of (on $\{0,...,9\}$) uniformly distributed random variables.

Show that  $X = \sum\limits_{n \geq 1} \frac{X_n}{10^n}$ is uniformly distributed on the unit interval.

I don't quite know how to start here, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [moment-generating function of a discrete uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution):

$$M_X(t)=\mathbf{E} \left[\mathrm{e}^{tX} \right]=\mathbf{E}\left[ \mathrm{e}^{t \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{X_n}{10^n}}  \right] = \prod_{n \geq 1} M_{X_n} \left( \frac{t}{10^n} \right) = \prod_{n \geq 1} \frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{\frac{t}{10^{n-1}}}}{10(1-\mathrm{e}^\frac{t}{10^n})}=\frac{e^t-1}{t}. $$
That is indeed the MGF of a continuous uniform distribution over $[0,1]$.